# Can't get value from DateTime object in PHP

Tags: php

I am facing an issue while trying to get value from an object in PHP. Here is the object:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2017-06-03 18:33:48.000000
    [timezone_type] => 1
    [timezone] => +00:00
)
```

it's all in this variable `$call->dateCreated`

and here is how I am trying to get the value of "date" from the object:

```
$call->dateCreated->date;
```

but when I try to do this, I got an error:

> Undefined property: DateTime::$date

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, so you can get wanted format date by calling [`format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) function:

```
$call->dateCreated->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

For date type objects, you can not access that value, you can access it through the richness of an expression by following a format.

I'll explain:

```
$call->dateCreated->date // It is not accessible
```

But if you ask the data in this form you will get the result

```
$call->dateCreated->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score -1):

This should fix it, try something like this

```
$date_array = (array) $call->dateCteated;
```

Then use the date value as

```
$date_array['date']
```

Hope this helps!